# Set element width to image inside it

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a page that displays an image, along with some metadata about it. The image and metadata should be centered in the page. I'd like the div containing the metadata to be exactly as wide as the image. Sorta like so:

[image: mockup]

Unfortunately, it's not possible for me to reliably determine the image's width before serving the page. Right now I'm using a listener on load:

```
$('.image-container img').one('load', function() {
    $('.image-container, .image-container *').css('max-width', $(this).width());
});
```

This works, but if the image is large and takes a while to load, the page looks crappy until it finishes. So I'm looking for either:

1. A way to use CSS to express that the container should be exactly as wide as the image inside it.
2. An event that fires as soon as the browser gets enough information to know the image's width (which is pretty early on, from what I can see).

Thanks!

Comment: just add display:inline-block to the div

Comment: I think the trouble is the parent div is expanding to fill content as the "metadata" columns fill up.  I wonder if this could be done with table display modes?

Comment: then I woudn't use javascript to know the width of the image. I would use it to delay metadata filling up before image loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy to do without any jquery. just set the container to `display:inline-block` like this:

```
div {display:inline-block; margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Example in this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oz606qyb/)** (image size 600px x400px)

Comment: Ops.. ty for the edition CBroe.. you beated me for a few sec :)

Comment: Hm. This works for the problem as I stated it, but I missed an important point. I want the container div to be centered in the page, which AFAIK means it has to be `display: block` and have a `width`.

Comment: No it doesn't, just wrap the current solution in a container with `margin: 0px auto;` and set `text-align: center` : http://jsfiddle.net/oz606qyb/11/

Comment: Ty tybliz. Looks Like I missed the part of centered in he page in the question so I got the credit with a not complete answer,

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez you didn't miss it; I edited it in after the fact once I thought it was a problem.

Comment: Nice to know Andrew. Ty to take your time for the last comment